# How to create a crosstab / coefficient table where columns and rows are the same in SQL / Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like

```
      col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
 id1 |  1     0      0      1      0
 id2 |  1     1      0      0      0
 id3 |  0     1      0      1      0
 id4 |  0     0      1      0      1
 id5 |  1     0      1      0      0
 id6 |  0     0      0      1      0
  .
  .
  .
 idN
```

How would I create a query such that I get a table like

```
      col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
col1 |  3     1      1      1      0
col2 |  1     2      0      1      0
col3 |  1     1      2      0      1
col4 |  1     1      1      2      0
col5 |  0     0      1      0      1
```

where each entry in the result is the number of times that some value of 1 in one column occurred with another column that had a value of 1.

I can get the diagonal values by doing the following:

```
SELECT 
sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4), sum(col5)
FROM (
SELECT 
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 ) AS total
FROM (
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) row_num, *
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(id), date, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM db.schema.table)
)
WHERE row_num = 1 AND total <= 1
ORDER BY total DESC);
```

I assume that I have to do some kind of pivot or various union all's but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a union of 5 selects and 25 case statements - 5 case statements in each select. It's quite an ugly solution I have to admit and will work only if you have a constant number of columns, but it will definitely do the job.

Comment: Ah I see, is there a way to do it if the columns are not constant?

Answer (score 0):

As you do not know the exact number of columns the idea ios to unpivot firs, manipulate and them pivot back. This should work:

```
-- identify table columns
with table_columns_list as (
select column_name, ordinal_position
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema like 'schema' and table_name like 'table' 
   ),
-- unpivot the table and add row id 
flat_table as (
select * from ( select * , row_number() as row_id from my_table)
unpivot(value for column_name in (select column_name from table_columns_list)
),
-- calculate all matrix values
full_flat_table as ( 
select a.row_id as row_id , a.column_name as a_column_name, b.column_name as 
b_column_name, min(a.value,b.value) as value
from flat_table as a inner join  flat_table as b on a.row_id=b.row_id
)

select * 
from full_flat_table
pivot(sum(value) for a_column_name in (select column_name from 
table_columns_list))
as p
order by b_column_name;
```