# How to create a pivot table where columns and rows are the same in Snowflake SQL?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table like

```
      col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
 id1 |  1     0      0      1      0
 id2 |  1     1      0      0      0
 id3 |  0     1      0      1      0
 id4 |  0     0      1      0      1
 id5 |  1     0      1      0      0
 id6 |  0     0      0      1      0
  .
  .
  .
 idN
```

How would I create a query such that I get a table like

```
      col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
col1 |  3     1      1      1      0
col2 |  1     2      0      1      0
col3 |  1     1      2      0      1
col4 |  1     1      1      2      0
col5 |  0     0      1      0      1
```

where each entry in the result is the number of times that some value of 1 in one column occurred with another column that had a value of 1?

I can get the diagonal values by doing the following:

```
SELECT 
sum(col1), sum(col2), sum(col3), sum(col4), sum(col5)
FROM (
SELECT 
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 ) AS total
FROM (
SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) row_num, *
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT(id), date, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
FROM db.schema.table)
)
WHERE row_num = 1 AND total <= 1
ORDER BY total DESC);
```

I assume that I have to do some kind of pivot or various union all's but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You asked the exact same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367657/how-to-create-a-crosstab-coefficient-table-where-columns-and-rows-are-the-same Why did you post it again instead of editing the original?

Comment: All your rows have exactly two "1"s.  Is that always true?

Comment: @forpas I did that because I was unsure if I was phrasing the question correctly and thought that phrasing it another way might give potential answer-ers a better idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that is always the case. Eventually I will expand it to up to 13 "1s" but for now I will just do two

Comment: What you did is copy/paste and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would approach this by unpivoting the data and re-aggregating.  The following gets the pairs and counts:

```
with u as (
      select t.id, v.col
      from t cross join lateral
           (values ('col1', col1),
                   ('col2', col2),
                   ('col3', col3),
                   ('col4', col4),
                   ('col5', col5)
           ) v(col, val)
      where val = 1
     )
select u1.col, u2.col, count(*)
from u u1 join
     u u2
     on u1.id = u2.id
group by u1.col, u2.col;
```

This seems good enough for me, but you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select u1.col, 
      sum(case when u2.col = 'col1' then 1 else 0 end) as col1,
      sum(case when u2.col = 'col2' then 1 else 0 end) as col2,
      sum(case when u2.col = 'col3' then 1 else 0 end) as col3,
      sum(case when u2.col = 'col4' then 1 else 0 end) as col4,
      sum(case when u2.col = 'col5' then 1 else 0 end) as col5
from u u1 join
     u u2
     on u1.id = u2.id
group by u1.col;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, just a couple questions (still new to this Snowflake thing). v.id is the id from my table correct? So if my id is called "XYZid", I put v."XYZid"? In that regard is v.col meant to be anything specific? I suppose then that t is just my table that I am querying? Last question, what is u1 and u2 referring to? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kwarner . . . I repeated the id in the lateral join, but that is not necessary.  I'll change the answer.  `u1` and `u2` are table aliases.

Comment: When I run the first query I get SQL execution internal error: Processing aborted due to error 300002:4143448929 (This is probably something that I have to take up with Snowflake). When I run the second query I get invalid identifier 'U1.COL'.

Comment: @Kwarner . . . (1) You have to run the second query with the `u` CTE.  (2) Snowflake supports both lateral joins and `values` clauses, so it is unclear what the error would be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach that showcases one of Snowflake's powerful semi-structured functions (namely, `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*)`) and also exploits two meta-attributes (`SEQ` and `KEY`) that are returned by the `FLATTEN` function so that there is no need for a unique business key on the original (source) table:

```
WITH CTE_ROW AS (
  SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) AS COL_DICT
    FROM T
)
,CTE_ROW_COL AS (
  SELECT F.SEQ - 1 AS ROW_OFFSET
        ,F.KEY AS COL_NAME
        ,COL_DICT[F.KEY]::INTEGER AS VAL
    FROM CTE_ROW R
        ,LATERAL FLATTEN(R.COL_DICT) F
)
,CTE_CALC AS (
  SELECT RC1.COL_NAME AS COL_NAME_1
        ,RC2.COL_NAME AS COL_NAME_2
        ,COUNT(*) AS COUNT_VAL
    FROM CTE_ROW_COL RC1
         JOIN CTE_ROW_COL RC2
           ON RC2.ROW_OFFSET = RC1.ROW_OFFSET
          AND RC2.VAL = 1
   WHERE RC1.VAL = 1
   GROUP BY RC1.COL_NAME
           ,RC2.COL_NAME
)
SELECT COL_NAME_1 AS COL_NAME
      ,SUM(IFF(COL_NAME_2='COL1', COUNT_VAL, 0)) AS COL1
      ,SUM(IFF(COL_NAME_2='COL2', COUNT_VAL, 0)) AS COL2
      ,SUM(IFF(COL_NAME_2='COL3', COUNT_VAL, 0)) AS COL3
      ,SUM(IFF(COL_NAME_2='COL4', COUNT_VAL, 0)) AS COL4
      ,SUM(IFF(COL_NAME_2='COL5', COUNT_VAL, 0)) AS COL5
  FROM CTE_CALC
 GROUP BY COL_NAME_1
 ORDER BY COL_NAME_1
;
```